# Using MongoDB field as key reference for another value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongo-shell

I'm still new to MongoDB, in an aggregate query I'm trying to use a value from a field as the key to getting the other value. For example in the following document,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9c245bb6c0ac7a34a43bf5"),
    "status" : {
        "code" : "ES004",
        "params" : {
            "star" : "VSP"
        }
    },
    "description" : "{star} has been added to the cast/crew officially",
    "stringToReplace" : "{star}",
    "valueToReplace" : "status.params.star"
}
```

I wanted to replace the value of `stringToReplace` in description with the value of `valueToReplace` (i.e., value in status.params.star which is VSP)

Is there any way of doing this in an aggregate query or only way to go with this is Mongo shell?